# Conjugation Classes inside the Orbit of close curve in Hyperbolic Surface under $Mod(S)$

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory, mapping-class-group

I've heard the statement:

> Let $S$ be a hyperbolic surface with boundary and $\left[ \alpha \right] \in \pi_1 \left( S \right)$ a non-trivial element that is not conjecture to boundary element,
> then there is some $ f \in Mod(S) $ such that the orbit of $\left[ \alpha \right]$
> under $f_*$ intersects infinitely many conjugacy classes, i.e. the set
>
> $$ \left\{ \left[ \left( f_* \right) ^{(n)} \left( \alpha \right) \right]_{conj} \mid
>  n\in \mathbb{N} \right\} $$
>
> is infinite.

Slight changes to the condition of the statement might be needed (I'm positive the statement is true, but state me corrected if its not).

There is a slightly nicer formulation of this statement with homotopy without base point, but I prefer this form.

I could not find any reference for this, and could not prove this myself, does anyone know how to prove this or can refer me to some proof?

Comment: Take a look at the theory of pseudo-Anosov homeomorphisms, in for example "Thurston's Work on Surfaces" (by Fathi, Laudenbach, Poenaru; translated by Kim, Margalit); or "A Primer on Mapping Class Groups " (by Farb, Margalit). What you want is true whenever $f$ is represented by a pseudo-Anosov homeomorphism.

Comment: You have to exclude sphere with three holes.

Comment: @LeeMosher I tried to look at A Primer on MCG, but didn't found any thing, do you know  to direct me to more specific point in this book?

Comment: I might write a full answer later but fiddle around with 14.24 in the primer to get the result you want. You should be able to also look around for stuff on growth rate of conjugacy class length, where it is known that with pA give exponential growth rate(might find more stuff on Out(Fn) and free groups but largely applicable).